# If $f(x + y)=f(x)*f(y)$ and $f(5) = 2$, $f'(0)=3$ and function is differentiable then $f'(5)$ is equal to:

Tags: functions, derivatives

I was trying this question using the functional rule:
f(x + y)=f(x)*f(y) ⟹ f(x)={a^kx}
With this we get a^5k=2...(1)
and k*lna= 3
But these equations don't make sense as they both are unsolvable

Comment: I agree with you.  No such function exists as you've defined it.  Where did this problem come from?

Comment: It was in a book which i was solving

Comment: Please, avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming, not in Mathematics

Comment: Also, you correctly used MathJax in the title, why didn't you use it on the body of the question?

Answer (score 0):

You were given too many initial conditions. You cannot compute $f'(5)$ because there's no function $f$ which can simultaneously satisfy $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$, $f(2)=5$, and $f'(0)=3$. Notice that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ and $f'(0)=3$ jointly imply

\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x+0)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x)f(h)-f(x)f(0)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x)\left[f(h)-f(0)\right]}{h}\\
&= f(x)\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\left[f(0+h)-f(0)\right]}{h}\\
&= f(x)f'(0)\\
&= 3f(x)
\end{align}

so $f(x)=Ce^{3x}$ for some constant $C$. Differentiating, we get $f’(x)=3Ce^{3x}$, so $f’(0)=3$ implies that we must have $C = 1$. It follows that $f(x)=e^{3x}$, so $f(5)=e^{15}$ and thus $f(5)$ cannot equal $2$.

Comment: Minor technicality, from the differential equation $f' = 3f$ you would technically get that $f(x) = Ce^{3x}$ for any constant $C,$ but because $f(x + y) = f(x)f(y)$ we must have $Ce^{3x + 3y} = Ce^{3x} \cdot Ce^{3y}$ meaning $Ce^{3x + 3y} = C^2 e^{3x+3y}$ and therefore $C^2 = C \to C \in \{0, 1\}.$ Clearly $C$ cannot be $0$ because $f(2)$ is nonzero, so $C = 1$ and $f(x) = e^{3x}.$ This is likely the bit that the book solution misses, and they probably go on to solve for $C.$

Comment: @StephenDonovan ah, you’re right!